# What is the best way to store global objects with NodeJS and ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to store data (most probably an object) so that it is accessible to my entire application. For example, info about my current logged in user (user ID and name).

I am wondering what the most efficient way is to do this in Node and Express?

After doing some research, I found a few ways, although most seemed quite unorthadox such as global objects (`global.myuser = {}`).

I also found that I could store an object as a module and include it where I need it, although I'm not too sure if data persists using this method.

What would be the best approach for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a module manage the data for you and then `require()` in that module anywhere you want access to it.  `require()` is cached so subsequent calls to it get you back the same module every time which works well for shared data without actually using globally accessible variables which and while maintaining proper dependency management (globals are generally evil in node.js because they don't show dependencies at all).

Please be aware that globally accessible data in node.js is shared by requests from all users unless you specifically make it only available to some.  So a variable like `global.myuser` sounds suspiciously dangerous unless the `myuser` is a server user (something there is only one of), not an actual user from a request.

Here's a simple example:

```
// shared_data.js
var myData = {someKey: 12345678};

module.exports = myData;
```

Then, in other modules:

```
 var sharedData = require('./shared_data.js');

 // you can access the sharedData object here
```

---

If you're trying to remember logged in users, then you need a more involved system that involves keeping track of a given user via a login cookie token and storing valid login tokens on the server that various requests can check to see if the user is actually logged in.

For logged in users with Express, I'd suggestion using `express-session` as it does 90% of the work for you.  You get an object for each logged in user that you can store anything you want in and that info will be directly correlated to only that user.

The session object for the current user will automatically be available in the `request` object on any incoming request.  And, you can pass that session object to any other function you wish to call from within a request.

Comment: Yes they will be logged in users. I require the server to know which user it is serving data to, so that I can include their ID through my MongoDB call to get back data that is only relevant to them. It actually didn't even cross my mind that however I stored the global data, it would be the exact same for all users. What if I used an approach like the `express-sessions` package?

Comment: See my answer about save the data per user: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37504339/1229624

Comment: I'd recommend using express-session.  See what I added to my answer.

Comment: @Aminadav - Why are you commenting to me.  If you want to address a comment to the OP, then either file the comment on the original post or use the @ syntax to direct a comment on your own answer to the OP.

Comment: I'm commenting to @Fizzix. He asked something in the comment above me, and I replied him.

Comment: @Aminadav - You don't seem to understand that your comment was addressed to me, not to Fizzix.  If it doesn't start with a username it's addresses to the person who wrote the answer you are commenting in.  And, Fizzix was asking me a question, not you.  If you want to address a comment to Fixxiz, then you have to put "@Fixxiz" in front of the comment.

Comment: I have attempted to install and use `express-session` although have a few messages within my console. Am I right in saying that the correct way to store a session is by using `req.session.userId = user._id`? Because in my console, I am getting two warnings: `express-session deprecated undefined resave option; provide resave option server.js:34:9` and 
`express-session deprecated undefined saveUninitialized option; provide saveUninitialized option server.js:34:9`. Both warnings are displayed when my server is started, not when I save the session.

Comment: Fixed the warnings easy enough with a proper use of `app.use(session...`. Although I am unable to get `req.session.userId` within any other routes. Always comes up `undefined`...

Comment: All good, set `resave` to `false` and is all working well now. Thanks @jfriend00.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `global` for saving the current logged-in user. The problem is that all the users, will have the same `global`. So guest user will have access to `admin` pages.

If you need to share data between express modules, you can add anthing you want to the `request` variable.

```
app.get('*',function(req,res){
    req.firstRoute=true
    req.currentUser=30
})
app.get('/othertoure',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.firstRoute) // = true
    console.log(req.currentUser) // = 30
})
```

Comment: The OP appears to want to store data per user for a logged-in user across requests.  I don't see how this accomplishes that.

Comment: He didn't say that he want it to work across requests. He said `entire app`. Every request, he should do validation, and add the user data to the `req` object. After that he can access to the data, all over the app (other routes), until the request ended